# Size hole needed to make my water vortex work properly

Tags: water, flow

Im making a water vortex for the front of my home. I've got an old plastic 6 gal water jug that im going to cut down to hold approximately 5 gallons. The water pump I have can pump up to 55 gal/hr. I don't want to run it at full speed all the time. I would like to run it at approximately 35-40 gal/hr. Wondering how large the hole in the center of the base should be to make this work properly, as to not have the water draining be more than what is being pumped. So the rate of water draining has to be less than the rate of water pumped, with the maximum rate of water pumped being 40 gal/hr. Who can help me?

Comment: A vortex in a jug doesn't drain at all until the fluid drag slows the movement of the fluid (so it approaches the center).  Diameter and the material of the bowl are important variables.